# How Can I customize browse button like this?

Tags: html, css

This is an image of a browse button for uploading file. I want to craete a browse button like in this image. How can I do that?

[image: PSD Screenshot]

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. If that image is actually a screenshot of some page, then why don't you simply examine the code? Since in that case you have the html and css, what are you missing? _Look at it!_

Comment: No, it is not a scrrenshot of any web page. I found it from a psd file. But I cant do that.

Comment: @arkascha:  A .PSD file is a layered image file used in Adobe PhotoShop. It is a Photoshop Document file.

Comment: photo-shope document

Comment: Ah, a photoshop formatted file. Why don't you say so right away? ;-) Then indeed you have a problem. Since that is a proprietary format you cannot really look into it. Even if you could it would be illegal to do so. So you have to guess. I suggest you start with the hint given below: one of the online "button wizards" that help you style a button. But I still don't see what the question is. It is a button. You can style buttons. _Do it._

Comment: If however you refer to the browser builtin button for a file select input element, then things are different. You cannot directly style that, since it is builtin. You have to replace it with a javascript based solution which mimics its behavor. _Then_ you can style it. There are libraries for that if you don't want to implement that yourself. But in the end it boils down to this: you finally have a "normal" html button which you can style however you like.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you do it! Steps:

1. We use `<input type=file>` for uploading files. But we don't actually display it.
2. We use our own customized `button` and redirect all clicks to our `<input type=file>`.
3. Every time our `<input type=file>` changes its value, we display it in our `span`.
4. We style our file browser form to anything we like.

The following were *made similar* to the image, *as close as possible.*

```css
.browse-field {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #999;
  
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #CACACA;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.15), transparent 13%);
}

.browse-field>input[type=file] { display: none; }

.browse-field .file {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 0 0.8em;
  min-width: 25ch; /* Modify as needed! */
}

.browse-field .btn {
  margin: 6px 9px;
  padding: 5px 14px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #CACACA;
  color: #FFF;
  font: inherit;
}

/* Modify the following styles as desired */
.browse-field .btn:hover { background: #DADADA; }
.browse-field .btn:active { background: #CACACA; }
.browse-field .btn:focus { box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $(".browse-field>input[type=file]").each(function(){
      var inpfile = $(this);
      inpfile.change(function(){
        inpfile.siblings(".file").text(this.value)
      })
      inpfile.siblings(".btn").click(function(){
        inpfile.click();
      })
    })
  })
</script>

<div class=browse-field>
  <input type=file>
  <span class=file>No file selected.</span>
  <button class=btn>Browse</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this website: http://css3buttongenerator.com
It will help you creating a Button like in your link.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. But it is not the same as I want. Pls see the image I gave.

Comment: you can create exactly your button. it is a generator.

Answer (score 0):

I think do you need this. Chick it out on : [click](http://jsfiddle.net/3cj3qr0y/)

```
<div>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name=""/> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Css

```
 form input {
        border:0px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    form .button{
        padding:5px;
        border-radius:3px;
    }
    div {
        border:1px solid #B2B2B2;
        border-radius:3px;
        width:33%;
        height:auto;
        padding:5px;
    }
```